# Connecting to a remote database using Analysis Services

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssas

I have to manage authentication in my Analysis Services in order to get access to cube data in Visual Studio. I can connect to my database manually in SMSS

[image]

But fails to connect to the same database in SSAS due to following issue:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how to handle this issue ?. I have even checked my SSAS Server in SQL Configuration Manager and it seems like it is running:

[image]

Comment: SSAS only supports windows Authentication, make sure you are logged in to the active directory before you try to connect.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? If so share your findings with the community please.

Comment: @Osman did you succeed connecting to SSAS cube by any method other than windows authentication?

Comment: Unfortunately. A Windows authentication is required. If you know the username and password of the specific user, which is allowed, you can actually create a new local user with a corresponding username and password and then cheat on Windows, which will allow you the access

Answer (score 0):

MSSQLSERVER means it is the default instance. Does it succeed if you remove \BI from the server name when you connect?

Comment: \BI seems to be name of the sql server instance, as this is what is being used to connect to database server, see the first image shared by Osman.

Comment: Then try starting SQL Browser and connecting to SSAS with \BI

Answer (score 0):

SSAS only supports windows Authentication, make sure you are logged in to the same domain on which SSAS machine is, before you try to connect. I had written this in comment above but it is an answer to this question.